# Add combobox to ListViewItem

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

I'm creating a Windows Form application using C#. The form contains a ListView. It's an application for a Red Cross Dispatcher.

The ListView has a list of all units. Each unit has a status. This status needs to be changeable. Therefore I want to add a comboBox with all available statuses to each ListViewItem. The Statuses are stored in a MySql database.

How can I do this?

Comment: A list view is not generally useful for data entry.  Use a DataGridView instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a Microsoft sample article showing exactly how to do this: [How to use a ComboBox control to edit data in a ListView control in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320344)

You'll just have to change how it loads its data.