# Combobox on ListViewItem in C#?

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

I see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956301/c-sharp-add-combobox-to-listviewitem)

But it's not solve my problem.

I want to ask that how to put combobox to listviewitem. I'm binding data to combobox. Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've done already?

Comment: this tutorial http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320344 is only one combobox to all listvieitems. Sorry, i don't have any idea for problem so i haven't write code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320342) has what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank @competent_tech, but as i say above. This tutorial is only guide one combobox for all listviewitems. Have you another link ?

Comment: Since the code to display the combobox is under your control (in the MouseUp event of the ListView), you can apply whatever logic you need to in order to control when the combobox is displayed.